# Values are not added in MutableLiveData<MutableList<String>>()

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, viewmodel, mutablelivedata

I am using a fragment and viewmodel where the list values are not updated in the viemodel when the function is called from my fragment.

This is in my fragment

```
class SettingsFragment : Fragment() {

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val binding = FragmentSettingsBinding.inflate(inflater)
    val application = requireNotNull(this.activity).application
    val dataSource = UserInfoDatabase.getInstance(application).userInfoDao
    val viewModelFactory = SettingsViewModelFactory(dataSource, application)
    val settingsViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory).get(SettingsViewModel::class.java)
    binding.settingsViewModel = settingsViewModel
    binding.lifecycleOwner = this
    settingsViewModel.addValueToList("hello")
  }
}
```

This is from my ViewModel

```
class SettingsViewModel(val database: UserInfoDatabaseDao, application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application){
    private val _sectionList = MutableLiveData<MutableList<String>>()
    val sectionList: MutableLiveData<MutableList<String>>
        get() = _sectionList
    fun addValueToList(listValue: String){
    _sectionList.value?.add(listValue)
    }
 }
```

When I try to print a toast message as _sectionList.value.toString() from my viewModel after trying to add values to the list, it shows null.

Thanks in advance for the help..

Comment: Haven't tried `_sectionList.value = listValue`?

Comment: Please provide the code where you show your `Toast` message.

Comment: `_sectionList.postValue(listValue)`

Comment: Thank you @Onik.. your solution worked for me.. It shows null only when I try to add a string value to the list by using add() we usually use for MutableList data type like _sectionList.value.add("Hello")

Comment: Thank you @Rafsanjani... Your solution worked... Only when I try to add a string value by using add() it shows null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you have not initialized the `MutableList<>()`.

```
class SettingsViewModel(val database: UserInfoDatabaseDao, application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application){

    private val _sectionList = MutableLiveData<MutableList<String>>()

    val sectionList: MutableLiveData<MutableList<String>>
        get() = _sectionList

    fun addValueToList(listValue: String){

       // In the following line: _sectionList.value is still null, so this will 
       // never call the add
        _sectionList.value?.add(listValue)
    }
 }
```

If you initialize with:

```
init {
    _sectionList.value = mutableListOf<String>()
}
```

it should work hopefully.